# Update drawing function of a DrawingArea

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk-rs

I want to update a cairo drawing inside a DrawingArea. I tried to achieve this by calling `DrawingArea::connect_draw(...)` with a new function as the parameter. My issue is that it does not replace the original drawing function, but calls both when showing the window.
Here is an example

```
extern crate cairo;
extern crate gio;
extern crate gtk;

use gio::prelude::*;
use gtk::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let application = gtk::Application::new(Some("com.example"), Default::default())
        .expect("Initialization failed...");

    application.connect_activate(|app| {
        build_ui(app);
    });

    application.run(&vec![]);
}

fn build_ui(application: &gtk::Application) {
    let window = get_window(application);
    let drawing_area = Box::new(gtk::DrawingArea::new)();

    // Set drawing function
    drawing_area.connect_draw(|_, ctx| draw(ctx, 0.5, 2.0));
    // Change drawing function
    drawing_area.connect_draw(|_, ctx| draw(ctx, 0.9, 1.0)); // <-- Why is this not working as expected?

    window.add(&drawing_area);
    window.show_all();
}

fn get_window(application: &gtk::Application) -> gtk::ApplicationWindow {
    let window = gtk::ApplicationWindow::new(application);
    window.set_default_size(500i32, 500i32);

    // Set transparency
    set_visual(&window, None);
    window.connect_screen_changed(set_visual);
    window.set_app_paintable(true);

    window
}

fn draw(ctx: &cairo::Context, param1: f64, param2: f64) -> gtk::Inhibit {
    ctx.scale(500f64, 500f64);

    ctx.set_source_rgba(1.0, 0.2, 0.2, param1);
    ctx.arc(0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.0, 3.1414 * param2);
    ctx.fill();

    Inhibit(false)
}

fn set_visual(window: &gtk::ApplicationWindow, _screen: Option<&gdk::Screen>) {
    if let Some(screen) = window.get_screen() {
        if let Some(ref visual) = screen.get_rgba_visual() {
            window.set_visual(Some(visual));
        }
    }
}
```

I expect half a circle to be shown. Yet the old, full circle is still there, even though I tried to replace connect_draw. How can I properly replace this?

Comment: The docs state that `connect_draw` is used to attach a signal handler (https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.WidgetExt.html#tymethod.connect_draw). It seems that you're adding a second handler, not reseting it.

Comment: I thought so, but I couldn't find any functionality to replace the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `connect_draw` function attaches another signal handler, but will not replace existing handlers. However, the function returns a `SignalHandlerId` which you should then be able to use to disonnect your original signal handler using the `signal_handler_disconnect` function (see https://gtk-rs.org/docs/glib/signal/fn.signal_handler_disconnect.html).

Comment: Do you either have an updated link (that one is broken), or know the specifics of how to call signal_handler_disconnect? This might be the solution to a problem I'm having as well, but I don't see where or how to call that.